# Instagram's heart animation mimic - FadeScale animation

Tags: android, animation, android-imageview

I'm trying to create an animation similar to the instagram double tap animation, where the heart scales up from center while fading in, and then it stays visible for a little and then scales down to center while fading out.

I'm using this animation:

```
public void animateHeart(final ImageView view) {
AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
animation.addAnimation(new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f));
animation.addAnimation(new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f));
animation.setDuration(700);
animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
view.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

It works well for appearing animation, but the animation doesn't reverse.
Also, I want it to animate only once.

May someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are only starting one Scale and Alpha Animation with your code.

This line :

```
animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

apparently does not work well in an AnimationSet, so you have to apply it to each Animation separately. I would recommend something like this  :

```
public void animateHeart(final ImageView view) {
    ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    prepareAnimation(scaleAnimation);

    AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    prepareAnimation(alphaAnimation);

    AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
    animation.addAnimation(alphaAnimation);
    animation.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);
    animation.setDuration(700);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);

    view.startAnimation(animation);

}

private Animation prepareAnimation(Animation animation){
    animation.setRepeatCount(1);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    return animation;
}
```

Dont forget the

```
animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

Or your heart will reappear when the Animation is finished.

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

```
           final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.bounce);

                // Use bounce interpolator with amplitude 0.2 and frequency 20
                MyBounceInterpolator interpolator = new MyBounceInterpolator(0.1, 15);
                myAnim.setInterpolator(interpolator);

                imgFavourite.startAnimation(myAnim);
```

Add anim folder in res folder. add bounce.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXScale="0.3"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.3"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
</set>
```

create MyBounceInterpolator.java class

```
public class MyBounceInterpolator implements android.view.animation.Interpolator {
    private double mAmplitude = 1;
    private double mFrequency = 10;

    public MyBounceInterpolator(double amplitude, double frequency) {
        mAmplitude = amplitude;
        mFrequency = frequency;
    }

    public float getInterpolation(float time) {
        return (float) (-1 * Math.pow(Math.E, -time / mAmplitude) *
                Math.cos(mFrequency * time) + 1);
    }
}
```